# Finding the root cause of `undefined reference` error

Tags: c, gcc, linker, linker-errors, elf

I'm trying to understand why I'm getting an `undefined reference` error during linking:

```
/home/amirgon/projects/esp8266/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-gcc -L/home/amirgon/projects/esp8266/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib -T/home/amirgon/projects/esp8266/esp-open-sdk/sdk/ld/eagle.app.v6.cpp.ld -nostdlib -Wl,--no-check-sections -u call_user_start -Wl,-static -Wl,--start-group -lc -lgcc -lhal -lphy -lpp -lnet80211 -llwip -lwpa -lmain build/app_app.a -Wl,--end-group -o build/app.out
build/app_app.a(routines.o):(.text+0x4): undefined reference to `pvPortMalloc(unsigned int, char const*, int)'
```

gcc complains it could not find the function `pvPortMalloc`.
However, **I can confirm this function exists in `libmain.a`!**

In the command line above, libmain is referenced by `-lmain` and library path is set to `-L/home/amirgon/projects/esp8266/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib`. 
When I dump symbols from `libmain.a` on that path I can find `pvPortMalloc` marked as `T`, which means that the symbol is in the text (code) section:

```
/home/amirgon/projects/esp8266/esp-open-sdk/xtensa-lx106-elf/bin/xtensa-lx106-elf-nm -g /home/amirgon/projects/esp8266/esp-open-sdk/sdk/lib/libmain.a | grep pvPortMalloc
         U pvPortMalloc
0000014c T pvPortMalloc
         U pvPortMalloc
```

So, did I miss something?
what could be the reason that gcc does not find the function although it exists in libmain.a?
How can I further debug this error?

Comment: Need to get your libraries after your .o files on the link line, I believe. Order is important in linking.

Comment: @FredLarson Wouldn't the `--start-group` / `--end-group` fix that? it should resolve symbols iteratively until all symbols are resolved.

Comment: I think that only works for .a files, not for .o files.

Comment: @FredLarson but there are no .o files on the command line. The application code is already on `build/app_app.a` which is the last library before the `--end-group`.

Comment: Oh. Well, I don't know then. Sorry.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Mixing of C++ and C code causes your issue.

This error:

```
undefined reference to `pvPortMalloc(unsigned int, char const*, int)'
```

Does not say that the symbol `pvPortMalloc` cannot be found. It says that the symbol `pvPortMalloc(unsigned int, char const*, int)` cannot be found,
and that is a C++ symbol.

This means that somewhere you are compiling C++ code which thinks there is a C++ `pvPortMalloc` function, whose symbol also includes its signature, but you only have a `pvPortMalloc` C function.

Likely your C++ code is including a header file that is not C++ clean, and you will need to do something like this:

```
extern "C" {
#include "some_header.h"
}
```

Where some_header.h is the header file declaring the pvPortMalloc function.

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not only order of object files and libraries on the command line is important, but also the order of object files *within* a library.

Anything that **resolves** a reference must come *after* the symbol is used, otherwise you might get strange linking problems.

The effect you see is a typical problem of a library that has been built with `ar` and the wrong object file order (some .o file using an external function that is defined in some .o file *before* the one that uses this symbol in the lib).

`ranlib <libfile>` is the tool that fixes this by creating an index for all objects in the library and should get rid of this problem.

Comment: This is a good advice, but it was not the problem is this case. The problem was mixing of C and C++ code.